# Transfer component in props with children method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Its possible to transfer component in props with children method?

I have to components:

```
 let a = (<div>
        <button onClick={TContainer.METHOD}>TuCLIK</button>
  </div>);

 <TContainer data={ restaurantList } component={a}/>
```

I want to call method in childen but create element in parent. I want to pass this component on props.

If its possible i dont know what writing in **TContainer.METHOD** to call childen method

Comment: Does it have to be passed in props? Adding it in children is better maybe?

Comment: @Peter I am looking a dynamic transfer element with action in my childer element

Comment: Is `TContainer.METHOD` a fixed method in `TContainer`

Comment: TContainer.METHOD its only example

Comment: `a` is not a component it's an expression. a component should be a function that returns a `jsx` markup. (or a `class` that extends `React.Component`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing a [component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)  in your props, it's an expression.
A component should be either a `class` the extends `React.Component` or a function that returns a `jsx` markup.
Now when we know that components are just functions, we know that we can pass parameters to them, hence we can pass a function reference as a parameter:

```
let A = (onClick) => <div><button onClick={onClick}>TuCLIK</button></div>;
<TContainer data={ restaurantList } component={<A onClick={TContainer.METHOD} />}/>
```

**Note** that [components should be capitalized.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment, sorry but i misunderstood your question i guess.
You can't pass a reference of a method from a React component like that.

- We can use couple of approaches regarding this scenario, one of them
  is to use `this.props.children` and pass the child component as a
  child.
  For example - `<Parant><Child/></Parent>`
- We can pass the child component as a prop.
  For example - `<Parent component={Child} />` or `<Parent component={<Child />} />`
- We can write the parent component as a [HOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) and wrap the child
  with it.
  For example - `Parent(Child)`

In all the above examples you can't pass directly a reference of a function that is declared inside the parent's scope (as a prop to the child).
In order to pass the child a prop within the parent's internal scope you should do it inside the `render` method.
For example:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <this.props.component onClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This is a snippet that demonstrate one of the examples above:

```js
const Child = ({onClick}) => <div onClick={onClick}>Im a child, Click me!</div>

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    }

    this.addCount = this.addCount.bind(this);
  }

  addCount(){
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{`Count = ${this.state.counter}`}</div>
        <this.props.component onClick={this.addCount}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => <Parent component={Child} />;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```